# Secure Administration Dashboard for Drupal

Tags: drupal, network-security

Good afternoon.

We have a client who would like to secure access to the administration panel.

- Front-end users still log into http://example.com/user/login
- Admins would log into a domain secured by VPN e.g. http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx/admin/login
- We are familiar enough with user hooks etc. so that using separate login forms to authenticate the admin users vs. regular users shouldn't be an issue
- Once the admin is logged in, they can continue using standard admin URL's (http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx/user/1#overlay=admin/structure)
- However, we want to create a visual separation between the admin and the front-end (no overlay)
- This means removing the ability for admins to do the "on-page" editing, and all content updates should be done through the admin dashboard
- This also means that if an admin is logged in and the visit the "public" URL, they do not see the admin dashboard up top.

Hopefully this makes some kind of sense.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not quite the same URLs you requested but has the same end solution. Install the Login Destination module https://drupal.org/project/login_destination and then create different pages/views/dashboards for the different roles.

We have a number of site where front end members get a customised homepage, content editors get reduced permissions on the admin area and admins who can get everything.

[image: login-destinationation]